# How to load media from local storage to cast video to Android TV?

Tags: android, casting, local-storage, android-cast-api

As from sample google casting-app we can cast video to Android TV via URL. I want to cast video from local storage. I have not found any solution yet.

Let me know if anyone have implemented it.

https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-android
(Sample casting app by google)

Comment: Then what is the problem exactly?

Comment: This app casting videos to Android TV via URL but I want to cast a video via Uri by picking a video from gallery.

Comment: Yes we know that already. You are only repeating yourself. Tell which problems you encountered instead.

Comment: I didn't found an option to set uri. Let me know if you know

Comment: MediaStore API used.

Comment: You are a programmer. And this site is for programming problems. So you should add that option yourself. If you have problems doing so show the code you tried and ask.

Comment: @snorlax thanks for reply. Can you please share an article or video to achieve this?
I tried to find on different mediums but didn't found yet.

Comment: Suggest to refer https://github.com/KaustubhPatange/Android-Cast-Local-Sample

Answer (score 0):

MediaStore API your problem solved

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media

used it